# Framework7 routes, load page from existing JSON string

Tags: javascript, ajax, vue.js, vue-router, html-framework-7

I have the JSON data load at the start, and also pull to refresh. During these times a small delay is expected. When going between pages, it should be snappy, so I am looking to use this already requested JSON for my page content. One of the JSON objects is the entire (small enough) html page.

I cannot find a way to use this, and instead am following the examples making a second JSON get request before loading each page (article). I would rather just load the JSON data once at the start and use it until refreshed with pull-to-refresh.

*** Currently Working, but using a second JSON get ***

```
{
  path: '/article/:article_id/',
  // This works after much turmoil.
  // sadly have to do a second json call. could have got with initial.
  async: function (routeTo, routeFrom, resolve, reject) {

  //Testing
  // import('window.TodayJsonDB['+ routeTo.params.article_id +'][\'html\']');
  // window.TodayJsonDB[routeTo.params.article_id]['html'];
  // [data['article']['article_html']
  // console.log(routeTo);

  // Get external data and return template7 template
      this.app.request.json('/__php/json1.php', { one: 1, article_id: routeTo.params.article_id }, function (data) {
       // console.log(data['article'][0]['article_html']);
        resolve(
            // DOM locked until resolve returned.
            // object with resolved route content. Must contain one of:
            // url, content, template, templateUrl, component or componentUrl
            {
             content: data['article'][0]['article_html'],
            },

        );
      });
    }
  // A day of testin but couldnt figure out how to use existing json feed.
  //asyncComponent: () => import('window.TodayJsonDB['+ params.article_id +'][\'html\']'),
  //el: window.TodayJsonDB[params.article_id]['html'],
  //el: import('window.TodayJsonDB['+ params.article_id +'][\'html\']'),
  //template: import('window.TodayJsonDB['+ params.article_id +'][\'html\']'),
  //template: import('window.TodayJsonDB[' + params.article_id +'][html]'),
  //asyncComponent: () => import('window.TodayJsonDB[' + params.article_id +'][html]'),
  //asyncComponent: () => import('window.TodayJsonDB[' + $route.params.article_id +'][html]'),
  //asyncComponent: () => import('window.TodayJsonDB[' + {{article_id}} +'][html]'),
  //asyncComponent: () => import('window.TodayJsonDB[11][\'html\']'),
  //content: window.TodayJsonDB[':article_id']['html'],

},
```

I already have this json get already; loaded when the app opens and updated with pull-down: `window.TodayJsonDB`

which contains:

```
    window.TodayJsonDB[data['article'][i]['article_id']] = new Array();
    window.TodayJsonDB[data['article'][i]['article_id']]['article_id'] = data['article'][i]['article_id'];
    window.TodayJsonDB[data['article'][i]['article_id']]['title'] = [data['article'][i]['article_title']];
    window.TodayJsonDB[data['article'][i]['article_id']]['content'] = [data['article'][i]['article_content']];
    window.TodayJsonDB[data['article'][i]['article_id']]['html'] = [data['article'][i]['article_html']];
```

So my question is; how can I use the content of `window.TodayJsonDB[article_id]['html']` to appear as the page content instead of having to do another JSON call when the user clicks a link.

My attempts in the code, commented out. Any other suggestions on how to approach the entire thing differently very much welcome.

Thanks as ever.

n.b. I tagged Vue as I believe closely related with Framework7. I am not using Vue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution, my working code snippet is below. I used the same async section and converted the array output to a string using `toString()`. Only appears to work in the async section.
Can now load up the JSON for everything at the start, one JSON call.

Maybe will help someone else with Framework7. Good Luck!

```
{
  path: '/article/:article_id/',
  async: function (routeTo, routeFrom, resolve, reject) {

    // Do we already have the JSON for the page?
    if (typeof window.TodayJsonDB[routeTo.params.article_id]['html'] != "undefined") {
      resolve({
        content: (window.TodayJsonDB[routeTo.params.article_id]['html'].toString()),
      });
    }
    else{
      // Try and get it
      this.app.request.json('/__php/json1.php', { one: 1, article_id: routeTo.params.article_id }, function (data) {
        resolve(
            {
              content: data['article'][0]['article_html'],
            },
        );
      });
    }
  }
```